# retrieving Exception Full stacktrace

Tags: java, exception, apache-commons, lang

I am trying to upgrade Apache commons lang from 2.4 to 3.1 in my project. My implementation has a  reference to ExceptionUtil.getFullExceptionTrace(e) which does not exist anymore in 3.1.
The reason of removal was listed as

> "Removing isThrowableNested, isNestedThrowable and getFullStackTrace
>   as they were all types of no-op once you got to JDK 1.4. LANG-491"

.
Few questions around this change:

1. I am confused if this means we need to explore some other way to retrieve full stack trace or we can simply replace with ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e) instead.
2. Any idea on what changed after jdk 1.4 to make the method redundant?
3. Can't we simply do e.toString() where e is my Exception instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java 1.4 introduced [getCause()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29) method on Throwable class which is a parent for all Exception classes. If you need to get a stack trace as a String, you can use ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e) or something like this:

```
  Exception e = ...
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
  String stack Trace = sw.toString();
```

See additional discussion about removing methods from ExceptionUtil on [JIRA issue LANG-491](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-491).

Comment: Thanks Eugene. The discussions lists "getFullStackTrace then makes little sense. In 1.4+ it only ever prints one item". How do I get the fullstackTrace then?

Comment: So is 'ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e)' a equivalent solution then or did i get something wrong here?

Comment: Yeah, It's still confusing if getFullStackTrace is still needed. After some research I see that getStackTrace() is enough and we don't need getFullStackTrace() , as Java 1.4, the notion that all Throwables could be linked to a cause was introduced.  Some reference reading :     http://www.dickbaldwin.com/java/Java057.htm     and    https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-904